# Can I ask about alternative ways to synthensize a product?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I found ways to synthesise a product I need as part of a university assignment. We don't have the equipment or chemicals in the lab to do this task.

Is it ok to ask on this site on how to sythensize product x using equipment y and z and chemicals a, b and c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that should be on topic. Please add what doesn't work for you and why, and provide enough context for what you intend to do.

I would also recommend stating what you thought about what also could work and ask about specific parts of that.

What is not on topic are questions like, how can I synthesise X, without providing own thought and effort and enough context. Those are likely to be closed according to the homework policy.